# Как обновить ядро Linux Mint через терминал?

Tags: linux, linux-mint

Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно обновить ядро Linux Mint до последней версии через терминал. Обновлял через Менеджер Обновлений несколько раз, но система с новым ядром не запускалась.

Comment: Так не обновляется или не запускается?

Comment: @donRumata, я так понимаю, он спрашивает как сделать через терминал, потому что в прошлые разы при обновлении через менеджер обновлений система переставала загружаться. Ну или у него есть бэкап и раз был не прошлый :)

Comment: @Qwertiy, ну тогда `sudo aptitude update && sudo aptitude -y dist-upgrade` чё сложного.

Comment: Да, одно ядро работает, а после установок через Манагер система не грузилась

Comment: @donRumata не помогло( новая версия ядра не установилась

Comment: Какое установлено щас и какое предлагает репа?

Comment: @donRumata сейчас стоит 4.15.0.20, предлагает 4.15.0.42-44

Comment: Я всегда обновлял через sudo apt update && upgrade. Буквально вчера обновился до 5.3.0-42-generic

Answer (score -1):

Если у вас amd64, просто от рута выполните:

```
apt-get install linux-image-4.16.0-0.bpo.1-amd64 linux-headers-4.16.0-0.bpo.1-amd64
```

Далее ребутаете системку, и грузитесь с новым ядром.

Если ответ не поможет, напишу более детальный ответ, как установить || собрать ядро.

Comment: Ты уверен, что человек, который сидит на минте и не умеет apt-get - будет собирать ядро? И потом ничего не сломает.

Comment: Там ниче сложного. Уверен, он сможет. И не надо тыкать, я вам не друг)

Comment: @1stSentinel31YearPerlHist такая версия  которую Вы написали мне не приходила, по этому я сделал следующее:
sudo apt-get install linux-image-4.15.0.42 && sudo apt-get install linux-headers-4.15.0.42. После этого мне установилось linux-image-4.15.0.42-generic и linux-image-4.15.0.42-lowlatency. С первого установленного ядра система запустилась, но упало разрешение, настройка яркости и тд, а со второго (lowlatency) не грузится.

Comment: Теперь вам надо  настроить разрешение!